# SQL query for words (not the sentence)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to query a single column (varchar):

sample datarows:

```
1) The fox jumps like a foo on my bar
2) Jumpers are not cool
3) Apple introduced iJump
```

**When** I enter a **search** criteria like... **jump**

**I expect** to get a resultset of: **jumps, Jumpers, iJump**
(So I dont want the complete row)

Currently I'm using MySQL (I'm open to suggestions as long it's open source)

Comment: What happens where there are more than one `jump`'s in the row?

Comment: What Type of SQL?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc...?

Comment: I suggest reading up on [full text search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). Depending on database, you may already have support for it.

Comment: I've never ever heard of a SQL-Statement doing this. I suggest looping the resultset with a regex for filtering. EDIT: Whoops! Google proofs me wrong. There may be support for it depending on your DB-System. But maybe the suggested solution is of some value anyway?

Comment: first occurrence returned is good, if more could be returned it's even better

Comment: extended with info, it's MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL, I might suggest looking into [LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/).

This open source library will provide you with additional regex functionality, including the [PREG_CAPTURE](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php#PREG_CAPTURE_SECTION) function, which extracts a regex match from a string.

Using this function, you could easily build a regex to return the match you're looking for... Something like:

```
\b\w*jump\w*\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting any row with your search criteria is easy:

```
SELECT sentence
FROM sentences
WHERE sentence LIKE '%jump%'
```

I'd probably do the rest in application logic, since doing it in the database doesn't help you at all.

Also, any method of splitting a string and handling it will probably be database-specific, so you would need to say which one you're using.

Comment: And "LIKE '%jump'"  to find jumps, Jumpers.          And "LIKE 'jump%'" to find iJump          And simple "LIKE 'jump'" to find jumps, Jumpers, iJump  :3   But i recomend use sphinx or lucene